# How to avoid multiple redis calls while reading a hashkey

Tags: performance, caching, optimization, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am caching hashmap to redis and reading a specific hashkey in the following manner:

```
var hashValue = redis.HashGet(rediskey, hashkey)   // RedisCall#1
 if (hashValue == null && !redis.KeyExist(rediskey))  // RedisCall#2
 {
   // load from sql and cache it to redis
 }
 else
 {
   return hashValue;
 }
```

I am trying to avoid that 2 calls I have to make to redis. Please advice on how would you solve this problem and do this in just one redis call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) instead to execute both commands in one request.